# no access to websites within a local network

Tags: mac, network-shares, apache-http-server

I have a mac mini and a macbook. On the mini runs a apache +php installed via macports. Everything works fine on the local enviroment. But I don't have access to the site with my macbook. 
When I start the websharing in the system configuration I have access to the personal site. But this is not what I want.
Has anybody an idea how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I want to connect over the ip of my macmini. It is 192.168.2.111
The error message is Server not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never run Apache on a Mac, but you may need to tell Apache to listen on your IP address as it may be listening on the loopback. You will need to find the config file. On Linux it's in `/etc/apache/`.

You would look for the line that says `Listen` it needs to read `Listen x.x.x.x:80` where `x.x.x.x` is your machines IP address, or you can use `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` to listen on all interfaces on port 80, since your mac seems to have a webserver built in you may need to disable the web server before starting apache OR make apache listen on a different port other than 80.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use `hostname.local` and not only `hostname` when you want to access the web site.